# Japanese characters displaying as random symbols

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have a Japanese program, but when I try to run it all the Japanese characters turn into random symbols like in the link to the picture

http://puu.sh/avcAp/04de126564.png

I've tried searching for answers but I only see ways to fix it if it shows up as blank rectangles and not the random symbols I'm getting.

You can see little bits of english just fine though, like in the link, you can see the .exe ... (I'm trying to install it but there's an error and since it's all these random symbols I have no idea what it means.)

Edit:

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate. This is a program I downloaded online, but I'm sure it's not broken. The symbols in the picture are a screenshot from an error window (The windows default one with a red X on the left), however all the text that's related to that program that is Japanese is also random symbols, and my picture is just an example.

Edit 2:
Here is a better image 
http://puu.sh/aveXV/7d15ecf2d4.png
Where you can see some Japanese characters, but some are random characters. This is when I first run the .exe to install and it's asking for what directory I want to install to

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What is the program? One you wrote? What OS are you using? How do you “try to” run it? Where are these symbols showing up? In the UI? In a file? Where did you get the picture from? A screen shot?

Comment: I guess it's a non-unicode program. Try AppLocale or NTLEA to start the program

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a non-Unicode program.  It's not ideal, but you can change your non-Unicode program language in Region and Language settings in Control Panel to Japanese (requires reboot).

It only affects non-Unicode programs, so most modern English programs will be unaffected.  I've changed mine to Chinese (PRC) and the only program I noticed affected was "cmd.exe".  It allowed me to type and display Chinese at the console.

[image]